# What should I use in this situation? (Code Igniter)

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I'm building online math exam, the user chooses the subject, and my program generates a view with all the questions from the selected subject. HELP IN THIS PART: After submiting the answers, I want that the system reload the page, preserving the selected options, and color the right options green.

Comment: [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For preserving selected options you should use codeignier form helpers:
http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/helpers/form_helper.html

I'm not sure what is the best practice for coloring the right answers. however when you calculating the form data to find the right answers you can simply add an item to each record for example answer is right or wrong ($records[$id]['answer'] = 'right';) then when  you generating the form, put this item as a class into your form items for example like this:

```
<div class="<?php echo $answer; ?>">
  ... form field ...
</div>
```

then just create some simple css rules like:

```
.wrong{background:red} 
.right{background:green}
```

i think it does the job for you.